# Creating a clustered column, 4 series, two axes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I ran a survey twice, each time measuring the impact to revenue and subscribership under 8 different scenarios. I now want to create a clustered column chart to show how similar the findings from the second survey were to those of the first. On the X axis will be the scenarios tested (1 through 8), and for each I want to display revenue impact according to survey 1, revenue impact according to survey 2, subscribership impact according to survey 1, and subscribership impact according to survey 2. Thing is, I need a secondary vertical axis because subscribership impact is measured in percent change ranging from -20% to +20%, and revenue impact is measured in millions of dollars, ranging from -$800 to +$800. For some reason when I take the final step, which is to tell Excel to plot subscribers on the secondary axis, the bars end up on top of each other and I can't figure out why or how to fix it!! Help!!

Here's what my result looks like:

[image: Messed Up Version of 4-series, 2-axis clustered column]